# which public rsa keybelongs to which secret?

Tags: ssh-keys, rsa

Is there a way to find out which public rsa key belongs to which secret key?

I have two pairs lying around, and would like to know ehich one is which.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ssh-keygen` can show you the public key of a given private key:

```
ssh-keygen -y -f <PRIVATE-KEY>
```

You can then compare the output with your public keys.